# Fraction pattern in c++

Tags: c++, for-loop

I need to write a program to run this pattern in c++:
[S=1/2+2/3+3/4+4/5+...+N-1/N](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2tGR.png)

I have tried but my code is showing 0.
And its the code that I have written:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned int N;
    float S=0;
    
    cout << "Enter N:";
    cin >> N;

    for (int I = 2; I <= N; I++)
    {
        S = S + (I - 1) / I;
    }
    cout << S;
    return 0;
}
```

I have to write it with for-loop, while and do-while

Comment: `static_cast<float>(I - 1)`. Otherwise you'll be performing integer divisions that will always be zero.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`(I - 1) / I` only contains integers, therefore any remainder is discarded.

You can avoid this by simply subtracting `- 1.f` off of `I` instead.

Comment: Please flag/vote to close obvious dupes.  Answering stops the roomba from cleaning them up automatically.